# set button visible in activity based on grid view image adapter item behavior

Tags: android

I have a grid view with three imageviews--> mainimage, eyeimage,tickimage

mainimage will load the image resources dynamically whereas eyeimage is image of an eye which you can see in the bottom left corner of main image and the tick image will show/hide on the right bottom corner of mainimage if you click on the mainimage.

The screenshots are
[None image clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M11Ij.png)

[One image clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfpie.png)

I want to show NEXT button which is in activity if any of the tick image is visible; for that am keep track of items whose tick button is visible.

Inside ImageAdapter

```
   public static ArrayList<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<>(); 
   ....................
   ....................
   ....................
    imageViewAndroid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(!pos.contains(position)) {
                    pos.add(position);
                    tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                else {
                    tick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    int index=pos.indexOf(position);
                    pos.remove(index);
                }

            }


        });
```

In order to show/hide NEXT button in activity what I did is implemented a countdown timer which will check the above integer array list every 2 ms and accordingly show/hide NEXT button

```
          CountDownTimer newtimer = new CountDownTimer(1000000000, 200) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            if(ImageAdapter.pos.isEmpty())
            {
                cli.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
            else cli.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void onFinish() {

        }
    };
    newtimer.start();
```

But I feel like this countdown timer will make the app slow in future. Is there any better way to implement this??